# Setting chrome driver executable path keeps causing my build to fail

Tags: azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6, robotframework

I have been fighting with this too long, and now decided to solicit help from those who have experience. I'm attempting to use chromedriver in azure devops environment, but when I set the path to chromedriver and run the script, it's not being seen. Below are some artifacts from of this issue. Any assistance is geatly appreciated:

robot script:

```
*** Keywords ***
Login
    #Open Webdriver hosted on Azure Devops
    Create Webdriver    Chrome executable_path=D:/a/1/s/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe


    OpenBrowser     ${url}       Chrome
    MaximizeBrowserWindow
    InputText       id=identifierId     &{LOGIN}[Username]
    ClickElement    xpath://div[@id='password']//input
    InputPassword   xpath://div[@id='password']//input &{LOGIN [Password]
```

Error:[image]

Comment: Is that your actual code? It looks like you're missing a space between `Chrome` and `executable_path`.

Comment: It is, but here it's just how it formatted in Stackoverflow. Also, I triple checked all of what might be perceived as a spacing anomaly. I'm baffled at how such a small thing (path) is so difficult to find an answer for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a tool for exactly this sort of scenarios. Since by the looks of it (robot framework stuff in the screenshot), you already have python set up. Install "webdrivermanager" pip package and call `webdrivermanager chrome --linkpath AUTO` before running the robot and chromedriver should be automatically installed in location that seleniumlibrary finds it and then omit the `Create Webdriver` keyword.

Code here: https://github.com/rasjani/webdrivermanager